# Replace a string by another if it is found after a pattern and before another

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, replace, regex-group

```py
import re

input_text = "Creo que ((PERS)los viejos gabinetes) estan en desuso, hay que hacer algo con ellos. ellos quedaron en el deposito de afuera, lloviznó temprano por lo que ((PERS)los viejos gabinetes) fueron llevados a la sala principal."

pattern_01 = r"((PERS)\s*los\s[\w\s]+)(\.)"
output = re.sub(pattern_01, r"\1, \1\3", input_text, flags = re.IGNORECASE)

print(output)
```

Replace any `"ellos"` substrings before the first dot `.` after a `((PERS)\s*los )` sequence with the content inside those brackets  `((PERS)\s*los )` which must be found before that occurrence of that substring `"ellos"`

Using this code directly does not modify the string

But I would need to get this output:

```
"Creo que ((PERS)los viejos gabinetes) estan en desuso, hay que hacer algo con los viejos gabinetes. ellos quedaron en el deposito de afuera, lloviznó temprano por lo que ((PERS)los viejos gabinetes) fueron llevados a la sala principal."
```

the number of times the replacement must be performed is not known, that is, there may be more than one `"ellos"` between `((PERS)ellos )` and the first point `.` after this word

Comment: It seems you forgot to escape the parentheses. Now they're being treated as capture groups.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal This pattern `r"\(\(PERS\)\s*los\s[\w\s]+\)(\.)"` give this error `re.error: invalid group reference 3 at position 7` what I need I do?

Comment: Try to match the capture groups to the substitution pattern using additional parentheses. The explanation is a bit vague, so try to look which parts should be captured and used in the substitution. Those parts should be in actual parentheses.

Comment: I would also recommend using [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) to see what your regex is actually matching and seeing what the different parts of your regex expression mean.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal I'm not sure what you mean by that, the goal of the program is to replace a subtring if it comes after `"((PERS))"` and before a period `"(.\s*\n|.|\ n)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```py
import re

re_block = re.compile(
    r"""
      (                  # 1. group recorded because it's kept
        \(
          \(PERS\)\s*
          ( los[^\)]* )  # Recplacment string in 2. group
        \)
      )
      ( [^\.]* )         # 3. group: part in which `ellos` gets replaced
    """,
    re.VERBOSE
)
re_ellos = re.compile(r"\bellos\b")

def repl(match):
    return match[1] + re_ellos.sub(match[2], match[3])

output_text = re_block.sub(repl, input_text)
```